# Dropzone js uploads images in the other form to fill. Laravel 4

Tags: php, image, forms, laravel, upload

I have a question.

How to make loading images in the form of adding ads.
Currently I have this:

http://screencast.com/t/2GZsvVjo8

I wants to do to load files looks nice, and I could delete the added image.

My view:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/create', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('id_category', 'Wybierz kategorię oferty') }}
        {{ Form::select('id_category', $categories) }}
    </p>
    <p>
      {{ Form::label('Wpisz tytuł:') }}
      {{ Form:: text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('Opis') }}
        {{ Form:: text('description', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('Cena') }}
        {{ Form::text('price', null, array('class'=>'form-price')) }}
    </p>

    {{ Form::file('images[]', array('multiple'=>'true', 'class'=>'dropzone', 'id'=>'my-dropzone')) }}

    {{ Form::submit('Create offers', array('class'=>'secondary-cart-btn')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

This line it has to be, because is responsible for the rest of the form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/create', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>true)) }}
```

In dropzone website is so that you have to add a Form :: open
**'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone'**

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `class` ,`id` or other else like the following

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'profile/offers/create', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>true, 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'my-awesome-dropzone')); }}
```

Read more about Laravel's Forms & HTML on [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html).

Comment: Yes, ok but when i add class and id to form then look is changing.
[link](http://screencast.com/t/lxAbH1xkHb2W)